# compute Power of integer Calculation from Greenplum to hive migration

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

We are migrating greenplum to hive and we are have to convert similar operation in hive, as below statement needs to convert hive. please help me.

Greenplum :

```
round(Payg_usage/(1024.00^2),2)
```

the operator `^` not supporting
Hive ?

Answer (score 0):

In hive you can use pow/power function. Below returns m to power n (m^n)

```
POW( double m, double n ), 
Or
POWER( double m, double n )
```

Use

```
Round(Payg_usage/pow(cast(1024.00 as double),cast(2 as double)),2)
```

Comment: i find the solution like , is it fine round(Payg_usage/(Pow(1024,2)),2)

Comment: Yes, but sometime casting is needed because it can throw error. Its to be more precise.